# Getting rows based on the max pair of two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table where I have fields like:

```
ID, COL1, COL2, BOOK, PAGE
```

And I want only one result per distinct `ID`. What I want to base this on is the maximum `BOOK` and `PAGE`, favored in that order. So I would select the rows that have the largest `BOOK`, and within those rows choose the one that has the largest `PAGE` for each and every `ID`. I'm writing SQL in MS ACCESS for this.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
ID  COL1   COL2  BOOK  PAGE
 1    X      Y     10    12
 1    X      Z     10    14
 2    Y      W     14     7
 3    J      K     15     9
 3    J      K     16     6
```

Say I had a something like shown above. I would end up with:

```
 ID  COL1   COL2  BOOK  PAGE
 1    X      Z     10    14
 2    Y      W     14     7
 3    J      K     16     6
```

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @Jsqsh did you get a chance to look over and try the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as [described according to my SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e1b8d/1) (for MySQL)

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Col1, Col2, Book, Max(Page) AS MaxPage FROM Table1
INNER JOIN 
   ( SELECT ID, MAX(`Book`) AS MaxBook
     FROM Table1
     GROUP BY ID) AS t1
ON Table1.ID = t1.ID
AND Table1.Book = t1.MaxBook
Group BY Table1.ID, Book
```

**Edit: Added code to work for SQL Server and MS-Access**

(apparently they don't let you include fields unless in GROUP BY clause

Same result - [different SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df7ed7/16)

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Col1, Col2, Table1.Book, Table1.Page FROM Table1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Table1.ID, Book, Max(Page) AS MaxPage FROM Table1
      INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT ID, MAX(Book) AS MaxBook
         FROM Table1
         GROUP BY ID) AS t1
       ON Table1.ID = t1.ID AND Table1.Book = t1.MaxBook
       GROUP BY Table1.ID, Table1.Book) AS t2
ON Table1.ID = t2.ID 
AND Table1.Book = t2.Book 
AND Table1.Page = t2.MaxPage
```

**Example of SQL Output**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t as t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.book > t.book or
                        (t2.book = t.book and t2.page > t.page)
                 );
```

Comment: From that I am getting where `BOOK` and `PAGE` are both blank, or these pairs:

`(BOOK, PAGE)`, `(43508200, 491)`,`("empty", 0)`, `("empty", 107)`, `("empty", 329)`, `("empty", 537)`

Which, with the blanks, came to 19 records when I expect around 110 thousand.

Comment: @Jsqsh . . . The query also needs a condition on `id`.